# Linking OpenCV 3.0. libs to QT creator

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I am working on vmware on Ubuntu 14.04

I can't seem to find a way to link libraries in qt creator. I have followed a really good tutorial [here](http:///usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so%20/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so%20/usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so%20/usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so%20/usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so%20/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so%20/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so%20/usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.so%20/usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so%20/usr/local/lib/libopencv_photo.so%20/usr/local/lib/libopencv_shape.so%20/usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.so%20/usr/local/lib/libopencv_superres.so%20/usr/local/lib/libopencv_ts.a%20/usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.so%20/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so%20/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videostab.so) and did exactly what it says but get undefined reference to:  when trying to build the project.

Opencv works fine when compiling from terminal.

I have created a QT project and added these lines to my .pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_highgui
```

I am not an experienced programmer, have I done something wrong?
I have searched for simmilar problems, but none of the offered solutions helped.

Thank you!
Petra

edit: contents of my whole .pro file:

```
QT       += core

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv
#LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_highgui

#LIBS += /usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_photo.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_shape.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_superres.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ts.a /usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videostab.so

LIBS += 'pkg-config opencv --libs'

QT -= gui
#QT += widgets


TARGET = Test
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

#CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
#PKGCONFIG += opencv

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you have to add to your .pro file is:

```
LIBS += `pkg-config opencv --libs`
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, I have seen similar suggestion before an tried it, but with no luck.
I have added in my post contents of the whole .pro file.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in QT += widgets!
So, combination of lines would be

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_highgui
QT += widgets
```

Also, important!

## If you don't make any changes within the source codes, rebuilding the project won't always recognize there have been changes within the .pro file!

That is why I had so much trouble linking it.
Hope it helps.